# A simpler (o rather direct) proof for $P(\{a\})=\big\{ \emptyset, \{a\}\big\}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification, alternative-proof

Here's my proof but I'm looking for a simpler or at least direct proof for the indirect part of this proof.

***Proof.*** Given two sets, say $a$ and $x$, it all boils down to stablish.\begin{align*}x\subseteq \{a\}\iff x=\emptyset\vee x=\{a\}\end{align*}
($\impliedby$)Trivial.

> It's trivial once we know $\forall S: S\subseteq S\wedge \emptyset \subseteq S$

($\implies$)Let us assume now, $$x\subseteq \{a\}\wedge x\ne \emptyset\tag{*}$$If there is $t\in\{a\}: t\notin x$ by the uniqueness of the empty set we know $x=\emptyset$, a contradiction to $(*)$ So it must be that $\forall t:\big(t\in \{a\}\implies t\in x\big)$. Furthermore, we know $\forall t:\big(t\in \{a\}\iff t\in x\big)$ also because of $(*)$Then,\begin{align*}\Big((*)\implies x=\{a\}\Big)&\iff \Big(x\subseteq \{a\}\implies \big(x\notin \emptyset\implies x=\{a\}\big)\Big)\\
&\iff \Big(x\subseteq \{a\}\implies x=\emptyset \vee x=\{a\}\Big)\end{align*}
as we intended to prove.

Comment: What’s the question?

Comment: What is $\land$ here? Certainly not intersection.

Comment: @Thorgott Conjunction.

Comment: What's the conjunction of two sets?

Comment: Ok, I figured out how your statements meant to be read now. I implore you to use brackets. Also, though more minor, I recommend not using $\colon$ to mean "such that" in plain text. Anyway, I believe you should add more detail to the argument "by uniqueness of the empty set". It is not very transparent as currently written at which point in the argument you take advantage of the defining property of $\{a\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to the proof by Hermis14 but more direct,  avoiding contraposition. As already observed, it suffices to prove that $\forall x\,(x\subseteq\{a\} \implies(x=\varnothing \lor x=\{a\}))$. So consider any $x\subseteq \{a\}$. Thus all members of $x$ (if any) are equal to $a$.

Case 1: $a\in x$. Then $a$ is the one and only member of $x$, so $x=\{a\}$.

Case 2: $a\notin x$. Then $x$ has no members at all, so $x=\varnothing$.

In both cases, $x=\varnothing \lor x=\{a\}$ as required.

Comment: I "get" why all members of $x$, if any, are equal to $a$ but, couldn't it be deemed as an heuristic argument? I mean it's plenty rigurous enough for me but I am wondering...

Comment: @Replik Since we assumed $x\subseteq\{a\}$, any element $y$ of $x$ must also be an element of $\{a\}$ (by definition of $\subseteq$) and must therefore be equal to $a$ (by definition of $\{a\}$).

Answer (score 0):

$
\newcommand{\ps}{\mathcal{P}}
\newcommand{\eqv}{\Leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\emt}{\varnothing}
$
By the definition of the power set,
$$
\forall x: (x \in \ps(\{a\}) \eqv x \subseteq \{a\})
$$
Let $P = \{\emt, \{a\}\}$. Then, we have to show that
$$
\forall x: (x \subseteq \{a\} \eqv x \in P)
$$
to show $P = \ps(\{a\})$.
Since you showed the $\Leftarrow$ part, I will show the other direction proof by contraposition:
$$
\forall x: (x \notin P \Rightarrow x \not\subseteq \{a\})
$$
Suppose $x \notin \{\emt, \{a\}\}$. Then, $x \neq \emt \land x \neq \{a\}$. There must be $b$ such that $b \in x \land b \neq a$. Hence, $x$ is not a subset of $\{a\}$.